# Left exact contravariant morphism is an isomorphism for fin. pre. modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

I was reading the proof of the following proposition:

> **Proposition.** Let $G$ and $H$ be covariant or contravariant functors from $A$-mod to $B$-mod, and let $\theta: G \rightarrow H$ be a morphism of functors. If $\theta(A)$ : $G(A) \rightarrow H(A)$ is an isomorphism and both $G$ and $H$ are covariant and rightexact or both are contravariant and left-exact then $\theta(M): G(M) \rightarrow H(M)$ is an isomorphism for every finitely presented A-module $M$.

The proof starts as follows:

> *Proof.* We consider the case when $G$ and $H$ are contravariant and left-exact. Since the functors are additive, they commute with finite direct sums. Therefore $\theta(F): G(F) \rightarrow H(F)$ is an isomorphism for every finitely generated free $A$-module $F$...

I am having trouble understanding why $\theta(F)$ would be an isomorphism.

By the definition of a morphism, we have that for every $A$-*mod* morphism $f$ and $B$-*mod* morphism $g,$ the following diagram is commutative:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G(A) @>{\theta(A)}>> H(A)\\
@V{f}VV @V{g}VV \\
G(F) @>{\theta(F)}>> H(F)
\end{CD}$$

We have that $\theta(A)$ is an isomorphism by assumption.

How do they use this and the fact that $G,H$ "commute with finite direct sums" to say that $\theta(F)$ is an isomorphism? Do we have to choose a $f,g$ accordingly?

---

**Notation:**

$A$-*mod* is the category of $A$-modules, where $A$ is a commutative ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $F$ is a finitely generated free module, given a basis for $F$ say $e_1,\dots, e_n,$ we have that $F=\bigoplus_i Ae_i;$ then, as $\theta(A)$ gives an isomorphism, $$G(F)=G\left(\bigoplus Ae_i\right)=\bigoplus G(Ae_i)\cong \bigoplus H(Ae_i)=H\left(\bigoplus Ae_i\right)=H(F).$$